# Is it possible to replace the result of the SQL Select query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a select query and is it possible to replace the data displayed from select statement. For ex, result from the my select query looks like

```
Name    Date    Total
----    ----    ----
No1    6/30/15    20
No2    6/29/15    35
No3    6/20/15    40
No4    6/30/15    65
No5    6/27/15    25
```

I want to do a calculation based on the date and replace the entire data in the cell with NULL or N/A.For above table, If the date is todays date then all the fields should remain intact else it should update as blank.

```
Name    Date    Total
----    ----    ----
No1    6/30/15    20
No2    6/29/15 
No3    6/20/15
No4    6/30/15    65
No5    6/27/15
```

Comment: You could do something like:
select name,date, case when date = getdate() then total else '' end from

Comment: Use select CASE when date = ... then total else 'N/A' end...

Comment: @Vignesh Show us the query.

Comment: select  ..., case when trunc(sysdate) = Date then date else null end from table;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either of:

- `DECODE`
- `CASE`

Using **DECODE**(looks shorter):

```
SELECT name,
  DATE,
  DECODE(DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE), total, NULL) AS "Total"
FROM table_name;
```

Using **CASE**(looks verbose):

```
SELECT name,
  DATE,
  CASE
    WHEN DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    THEN total
    ELSE NULL
  END AS "Total"
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Case option works fine. Another difficulty is how can I extend the same to multiple Columns. I tried with Nested Case and ended up with an error

Comment: @Vignesh I can't see the error, I can't see your query, so I don't know what you mean.